# How to change language in visual studio 2015 completely?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have my Visual Studio 2015 Community installed in Simplified Chinese version. Now I want to try it in English version.

I have already changed `Language` in `Tools | Options... | Environment | International Settings` to `English`.(I downloaded and installed the English language pack from the link showed below the button.) Now most of the things in my Visual Studio windows are represented in English. Yet, some items have not changed. For example, `References` in `Solution Explorer` is still in Chinese.

What extra steps should I take to completely change language in Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Comment: My personal solution would very quickly be: Uninstall/reinstall. I've dealt with so many issues in VS that would never go away completely without that somewhat drastic step. Also, it ensures that your environment is back into an easily reproducible state, you never know what other things may have lingered.

Answer (score 2):

go to Menu ->tools--->invironment --->international sittings--->get additional languagues